# In Laravel, how to detect "422 Unprocessable Entity" with JSON response?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am now trying to get the response from the server, if the server response `422 Unprocessable Entity`, I could modify my function so that we can have different reponses to users.

Now there are 2 potential errors, the first one is

1) User doesn’t have enough funds or their credit card is declined for any reason

```
{"errors": ["The credit card on file could not be charged."]}
```

2) User is already subscribed to the product

```
{"errors": ["Cannot reactivate a subscription that is not marked \"Canceled\", \"Unpaid\", \"Trial Ended\", or \"On Hold\"."]}
```

the response is sent through JSON and I'm wondering what could I do in Laravel to detect these two problems? Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: You question title and the final request doesn't align. When you have validation errors, the json response with errors are sent with the status code 422. You can check status code of the response to handle it appropriately. Your second part of calling those problems is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `Exceptions\Handler.php` file to handle those exceptions properly.

```php
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    // 404 Errors
    // Either the route does not exist or a model is not found when performing an Eloquent query
    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException || $e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Not found'
        ], 404);
    } elseif ($e instanceof HttpException) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Unsupported Media Type'
        ], 415);
    } elseif ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Forbidden. Unauthenticated.'
        ], 403);
    } elseif ($e instanceof QueryException) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Unresolvable Query.',
            'message' => $e->getMessage()

        ], 400);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

As you can see you can catch the Exception and return a proper JSON response.

To better differentiate if you want to return JSON or a 'normal' message, you can check with `if($request->ajax()) { ... } else { ... }` if you request is an AJAX request and you want to return JSON or sth. else.